# Converse direction of the Zariski connectness theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

One has the following Zariski connectness theorem

If a proper morphism $\pi: X \rightarrow Y$ of locally Noetherian schemes which has $\mathcal{O}_Y \cong \pi_* \mathcal{O}_X$, then $\pi^{-1}(q)$ is connected for every $q \in \mathrm{Y}$.

---

In Popa's notes (see [here Remark 1.2.9](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Empopa/271/Kodaira-posted.pdf)) there is a remark which states that

REMARK 1.2.9. (1) Note that for an arbitrary projective morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$, the assumption $f_* \mathscr{O}_X \simeq \mathscr{O}_Y$ implies that $f$ is surjective, with connected fibers...

(2) Moreover, by a variant Zariski's Main Theorem, under the normality assumption the connectedness of all the fibers is in fact equivalent to $f_* \mathscr{O}_X \simeq \mathscr{O}_Y$ ...

---

I can't find the source of the second statement, I can only find the version which says that proper birational morphism into normal variety has $f_*\mathscr{O}_X\cong \mathscr{O}_Y$. It seems not to be the one that Popa state in the notes?

Comment: I find another one, which appears in Gortz and Wedholm Exercise 12.29 (which shows that needs generic fiber being integral + normal condition)?

Comment: Rem. 1.2.9 (2) is not true as stated I think. Consider the Frobenius morphism from a curve over a finite field to itself. This has connected fibres but the second condition is not satisfied. Popa probably assumes char. $0$ somewhere. See also Th. 37.53.4 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03GX

Comment: Thank you Damian Rössler

Comment: I found a proof in char 0 case in Section 1.13 in Debarre's Higher-Dimensional Algebraic Geometry